# Redirect all non www visitors to the www

Tags: apache-http-server, mod-rewrite

I keep getting variations of the following answer, and it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.alwaysroaming.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.alwaysroaming.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The reason this solution is no good is that if I go to

alwaysromaing.com/site

I'll never get be redirected to the WWW.alwaysroaming.com/site

Can anyone provide the correct rewrite required here?

Comment: Already answered at length, for rewriting in both directions, on ServerFault and StackOverflow [over](http://serverfault.com/questions/190589/) and [over](http://serverfault.com/questions/155658/) and [over](http://serverfault.com/questions/199342/) and [over](http://serverfault.com/questions/225974/) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/) and [over](http://serverfault.com/questions/210709/) and [over](http://serverfault.com/questions/186271/) and [over](http://serverfault.com/questions/446/) and [over](http://serverfault.com/questions/251474/) again.

Comment: Wow man I had to plus one your comment as it is amazing how much effort you put into that, finding all of them and linking them like that. Love it!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.alwaysroaming.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.alwaysroaming.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The key part is the '/' after the '^' in the second line.
The NC in means it'll work if someone types in mixed/upper case.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a common question that it's part of the [documentation for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#canonicalhost) - which you did read, right?

Assuming you're running on port 80:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^fully\.qualified\.domain\.name [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://fully.qualified.domain.name/$1 [L,R]
```

the documentation has another example in case you're not on port 80, and covers other common scenarios